# Markup customization

Tags: summernote

any chance I can somehow customize markup in the editor?

Case: I am using Standard Notes and my internal Wiki editor and it seems that is very similar to your editor, but have own markup. I want to write dоwn in Standard Notes and copy-paste in Wiki later.

For example, the thing is that Generic List works differently.
Here is how it looks in Plus Editor:

```
* test
    * test
        * test
        * test
* test
* test
```

And here is our Wiki:

```
* test
  * test
    * test
    * test
* test
* test
```

Any chance to have a tweak for that? Or can I somehow edit that in code by my own? I do not know how to program, JFYI :)

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: @Shai, sry, 1st time posting here, tag edited to summernote